AccessDeniedException to perform StartQuery When using Lambda to query CloudWatch Logs
I have a requirement to query the Cloudwatch logs and get the results through AWS Lambda.My cloudwatch logs are encrypted with KMS key I have given permissions in kms key policy as well to lambda role. I have assigned an IAM role with all the necessary permissions.
But still i facing this issue..
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQuery operation: User with accountId: xxxxx  is not authorized to perform StartQuery on resources xxxxxx(log group).
This is the role which I have assigned to lambda.
    "Policy":{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid":"Testlogsquery",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
          "logs:GetLogEvents",
          "logs:FilterLogEvents",
          "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
          "logs:StartQuery"         
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-1:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-2:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-3:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-4:*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "logs:GetQueryResults"          
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:GenerateDataKey"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:xxxxx:key/xxxxx",
          "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:xxxxx:key/xxxxx"
        ]
      },
     
  "Services":[
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
 ]
}




Can anyone help me here please?


Your Resources section is defined wrong for the StartQuery operation. You should pass log groups ARNs, not log streams, so instead of:
"Resource": [
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-1:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-2:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-3:*",
          "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-4:*"
        ]

it should be:
"Resource": [
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-1",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-2",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-3",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-4"
    ]

Considering you have Actions that require the previous resources to be defined, you should separate StartQuery into another block, like:
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "logs:StartQuery"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-1",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-2",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-3",
      "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:log-group-4"
    ]
}

